# Simulate `cd` command with PHP

Tags: php, symfony, cd

I am making a CLI-tool for work using the [`symfony/console`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html) composer package. (Much like [`laravel/installer`](https://github.com/laravel/installer))

The goal of this tool is to improve the daily workflow for my coworkers.

My `[COMPANY] install` command installs all active repositories in the current working directory. I save this directory in a configuration file on the home directory.

I now want to add a `[COMPANY] cd` command which should simulate an actual `cd` command by changing the current directory of my terminal to the install directory. So far, I have tried the following:

**What I already tried**

```
protected function handle(): void
{
    $config = new Config;
    $path = $config->get('directory');

    if (is_null($path)) {
        $this->error("It seems like you didn't install the [COMPANY] projects. Take a look at the `[COMPANY] install` command.");
        exit;
    }

    // These options do not work because they are executed in an isolated sub-process.
    chdir($path);
    exec("cd $path");
    shell_exec("cd $path");

    $this->info("Changed working directory to $path");
}
```

The `chdir()` method only changes the working directory of the current php script. While `exec()` starts a completely isolated process.

**Desired behaviour**

```
~                     cd ~/Development/Company
~/Development/Company company install
~/Development/Company cd ~
~                     company cd
~/Development/Company
```

My question: Is this kind of behavior even possible with PHP? And if so, how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would this help? http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Nope, shell_exec also starts a seperate process. I want to hook something to the terminal itself or something. I will add `shell_exec` to my post.

Comment: How about `exec('cd ~/Development/Company && company install && cd ~')`?

Comment: I do not want to install after cd. I want to navigate the user to the working directory

Comment: Just to understand, you want to run the PHP script in Terminal, and when it has finished, you should be in another folder because PHP has redirected you?

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea Yes. I want to 'simulate' a `cd`.

Comment: The only way i can think of is making a Bash script that starts the PHP script and then does CD when it ends.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea Is there a way I can integrate that nicely with my CLI-tool? e.g. `symfony/console`? Or should a make a completely new bash script for this?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot change the working directory of a terminal by running a script in it.

`cd` is a command built into your shell, not an external command in e.g. `/bin`.

Comment: Do you have a source? Or is this common knowledge? How does the actual `cd` command do it? Or is this a command that is protected by the OS?